# How to redirect user to external website from Modal window?

Tags: modal-dialog, razor-pages

I am working in razor pages, i try hard to redirect user to other page but nothing happen when i click on my anchor neither button.

Tried also redirect using ajax with  `window.location.replace = "www.google.com";` but i am getting full path anyway and therefore wrong redirecting.

This is my modal

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="display: flex; justify-content:center;">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Tittle of modal</h5>
               
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body d-flex justify-content-center">
               custom text
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              
                <a href="www.google.com" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">RedirectTOGoGle</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe remove `data-bs-dismiss="modal"`?

Comment: thank you, i removed that and inserted full path "Http//www.mywebsite.com and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the full url.  in this case the url is "https://www.google.com"